# How to step wise post data to an object using the Django-Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to post an object with Django-Rest Framework to my backend. The object contains multiple nested objects, and the user inserts this information setp-wise via a React JS frontend.

```
class Story (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    images = models.FileField(upload_to='audio_stories/',validators=[validate_file_extension_image], 
    blank=False)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio_stories/',validators=[validate_file_extension_audio], blank=False)
```

I now wonder how it is possible to send the data to the server step by step. Is there a way to initiate a story object at the very beginning of the creation process to generate its primary key and then add the other data to this key step by step, e.g. images and audio? I've already searched for the right term  in the Django documentation, but I'm having difficulties to approach this topic.

I am happy for any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create multiple endpoints and serializers for your `Story`:

```py
class StoryBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(...)
    date_posted = serializers.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    
        class Meta:
            model = models.Story
            fields = ['title', 'date_posted', 'id']

class StoryContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = serializers.TextField(...)
    images = serializers.ImageField(...)
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    
        class Meta:
            model = models.Story
            fields = ['content', 'images', 'id']
#and so on
```

then, create the endpoints:

```
# e.G. /api/v1/stories

CreateStoryView(views.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = StoryBaseSerializer
    # standard api code....
```

and then your views which modify the `Story` object:

```py
# e.G. /api/v1/stories/content/<int:pk>
UpdateStoryContent(views.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = StoryBaseSerializer
    
    def get_object(self):
        story_id= self.kwargs['pk']
        story = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), id=story_id)
        return story;

#and a view for each serializer you have defined.
```

Of course, another (and maybe much more elegant way) would be to define a second serializer (in addition to the `StoryBaseSerializer`) that makes all fields optional (non required, simply set the `required` flag in the serializer field to `False`) and updates the `Story` data with the fields that are set.

Something along the lines of this:

```py
class UpdateStorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = serializers.TextField(required=False, ...)
    images = serializers.ImageField(required=False...)
    # all your other fields go here
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = models.Story
        fields = ['title', 'date_posted', '...', 'id']
```

and then create a single update view, simply the same as above but probably at another endpoint, let's say `api/v1/stories/<int:pk>`. Now, within your react views, you simply post *only* the data you want to update. For example you post to `api/v1/stories/17`:

```json
{
   "content" : "... the content ...."
}
```

or:

```json
{
   "audio" : "blob data of your audio file"
}
```

This would only update the content of the story with the id 17.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It was sending me in the right direction. One question that arises for me from that what happens when the user quits the story creation process and not entering all data. Is than a "half finished" story in my data base?

Comment: Well, yes. But you could get around this quite easily. You only provide one endpoint, a simple POST endpoint. And you guide the user through the creation process in the frontend, storing all intermediate information there. And only when the story is finished (complete), you do a full POST to your endpoint. Think about how facebook (probably) does this... Do you really think they create a DB entry as soon as you start typing? They hit the DB when you hit "post". Everything thats optional for a story can be set later on via a PUT or PATCH. Only create (POST) the story when all....